# GDI Leak Problem

Tags: c, winapi, memory-leaks, gdi

I'm experiencing memory leaks while running the following GDI code:

```
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen); 
HBITMAP hbmpOld = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(hdcMem, hBmp); // apparently here is the leak 

// do something

SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmpOld); //placing the old object back. The return object is handled elseware
DeleteDC(hdcMem);  // after CreateCompatibleDC
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen); // after GetDC
```

I already looked at similar threads, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482083/gdi-leak-problem) but I couldn't find the problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

DeleteDC, ReleaseDC return value was checked to be true (no errors).

Thanks,
Tal.

Comment: what makes you think there is a gdi leak there? Taskmanager has a column that shows the number of GDI handles allocated by a process. Does the count go up if this code is run in a loop?

Comment: This code doesn't leak, it is elsewhere.

Comment: I can see the that the application memory usage in Windows Task manager is constantly increased, unless I remark the SelectObject line.
It means that the leak is cause by SelectObject.
I use hBmp in other parts of the code, I create it only once and delete it when I'm done.

Comment: Are you missing a DeleteObject(hBmp) call?

Answer (score 4):

Solved.
The problem was hBmp wasn't correctly initialized, so there was a crash at the SelectObject - no error, just the function exited, skipping the "//do something" and the releases part.

Comment: I'm glad that you figured it out. For future problems, this is a good example of why you need to post *as much of your code as possible*. I continue to work on my psychic debugging skills, but there's not a very good chance any of us can catch an error in code that we can't see!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, a very useful free tool is [NirSoft GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) which displays GDI usage per process and tracks changes (handle leaks) while it runs. So you can perform operations in your app and keep checking GDIView until you see the counter increasing, and then repeat the operations until you pinpoint which one is causing the unwarranted handle increase.